# Diagram of field theory

Tags: diagrams

I want to write this picture in LaTeX, what is the code?

[image]

Comment: Please show what you've tried... Can you do that?

Comment: you are really mis-using this site, you can not keep posting pictures and asking people to code them for you.  Try coding them and if you get a tex error post your code and ask for tex help

Comment: Is your problem solved? If yes, then accept one of the provided answers.

Answer (score 5):

Using `tikz`:

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}

    \node (Q1) at (0,0) {$\mathbb{Q}$};
    \node (Q2) at (2,2) {$\mathbb{Q}\Big[\sqrt{2}\Big]$};
    \node (Q3) at (0,4) {$\mathbb{Q}\Big[\sqrt[3]{2} \, ; \sqrt{2}\Big]$};
    \node (Q4) at (-2,2) {$\mathbb{Q}\Big[\sqrt[3]{2}\Big]$};

    \draw (Q1)--(Q2) node [pos=0.7, below,inner sep=0.25cm] {2};
    \draw (Q1)--(Q4) node [pos=0.7, below,inner sep=0.25cm] {3};
    \draw (Q3)--(Q4);
    \draw (Q2)--(Q3);
    \draw (Q1)--(Q3);

    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome back and I'm happy :-) You have my approval for your answer given.

Answer (score 4):

I use instead....`xy` package... to draw the image of the user. I put a screenshot of my MWE.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage[all]{xy}

\begin{document}

\[
\xymatrix@R+1.5pc@C-0.3pc{
    &\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt[3]{2};\sqrt{2}]\ar@{-}[ld]\ar@{-}[rd] \ar@{-}[dd]\\
    \mathbb{Q}[\sqrt[3]{2}] \ar@{-}[rd]_3 &&\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2}]\ar@{-}[ld]^2\\
    & \mathbb{Q} & 
}
\]
\end{document}
```

The lines are straight and is only an optical effect of the Papeeria display. 
[image]

Comment: @down-voter: What is the reason, please, of the downvote for me, Zarko and Milo?

Comment: One reason could be that if you downvote three times you are harder to spot. Downvoting at the beginning of the week is dangerous since you can be identified rather easily *unless* you take some precautions. (Needless to say that it wasn't me.)

Answer (score 3):

With use of the `tikzcd` package:

```
\documentclass[border=32mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzcd}[row sep=huge]
    & \mathbb{Q}\Bigl[\sqrt[3]{2} \, ; \sqrt{2}\Bigr] 
      \ar[dl,-]\ar[dd,-]\ar[dr,-]     &                          \\
\mathbb{Q}\Bigl[\sqrt[3]{2}\Bigr]\ar[dr,"3" ',-]
    &                           & \mathbb{Q}\Bigl[\sqrt{2}\Bigr]
                                  \ar[dl,"2",-]               \\  
    & \mathbb{Q}                &
    \end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

With `tikz-cd`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz, tikz-cd}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}[arrows=dash, row sep=3.5em, column sep=1.5em]
& \mathbb{Q}\Bigl[\sqrt[3]{2},\sqrt{2}\Bigr] \dlar\arrow[dd] \drar\\
\mathbb{Q}\Bigl[\sqrt[3]{2}\Bigr] \drar["\textstyle 3",swap]& & \mathbb{Q}\Bigl[\sqrt{2}\Bigr]\dlar["\textstyle 2"]\\
& \mathbb{Q}
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

[image]