# Diagram of splitting field using TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

I want to do something like this diagram in Cox *Galois Theory* book, using TikZ:

[image: splitting field]

Based on [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/513118/diagram-of-field-theory) I got the nodes and arrows, but I don't know how to do the upward subset symbol.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You should always provide a small example of code. However, I think, your question already has an answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/458361/47927).

Comment: It iiis, thank u so much :D